# iOS Swift Relative font size

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I have a UITextView, and I want to change its font size.
however, I want it to change relatively since it pulls from a file that has multiple font sizes in it and I want it to change accordingly.
for example, I have a word in font size 36 and one in font size 12 and I want to scale them by 0.75% to 27 and 9 respectively.

If I try:

```
textview.font = UIFont(name: textview.font.fontName, size: 20)
```

it will only change the entire UITextView font size.

thanks!

Comment: What kind of file? How are you specifying the font in the file?

Comment: it's an rtf file that has the font sizes in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this extension:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
  @warn_unused_result
  func scaleBy(scale: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let scaledAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
    scaledAttributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, inRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: scaledAttributedString.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (value, range, _) in
        if let oldFont = value as? UIFont {
            let newFont = oldFont.fontWithSize(oldFont.pointSize * scale)
            scaledAttributedString.removeAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, range: range)
            scaledAttributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range)
        }
    }
    return scaledAttributedString
  }
}
```

Then just call something like:

```
textField.attributedText = textField.attributedText!.scaleBy(0.5)
```

Example:

[image: Example in playground]

Comment: i added the extension at the bottom of the file and tried it but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: The extension adds the function `scaleBy` to `NSAttributedString`. You can use that function to scale the whole content of the `attributedString` property of your `UITextView` (like in the example)

Comment: @Benny note that you have to assign the result of `scaleBy` to `textView.attributedText`, only calling `scaleBy` won't have any effect

Comment: I added `@warn_unused_result` to the function so that you get a warning if you calculate it without using it

Comment: yup, forgot to assign it. dumb me :) thanks!! marked as answered

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write (or find) a parser for the rich text format file that could extract the font size data for each text element (I think this would be the `\fsN` tags in most cases) and then use that number (multiplied by 0.75) to set the size of each word or phrase individually. You could use an attributed string if the differently sized words need to be recombined into a single string, but that wouldn't be necessary if each word or phrase was in a separate label.

Personally, I would disregard the font sizes of the source data and impose a layout within the app that looks nice, if that's an option.